# Is it possible to download S3 Files using Boto3 inside a running Cloud Run instance upon request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have recently started building my API. When an API call is triggered, this API downloads a ~100kb file from my public S3 bucket every time a request is made. I have also attached my AWS credentials to the container. However, I am being returned with this error:

```py
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in
request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in
request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", 
line 701, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in
send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/sound/0242ac110008339dfea4bac27066daf9374ee057c869.mp3 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection 
object at 0x3e27cb590d00>: Failed to establish a new connection:
[Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're running the Cloud Run app in VPC? Does it have outbound network access to the internet?

Comment: You can run Python apps including AWS Boto apps in Cloud Run. Show your code that is creating the error. Also include the Cloud Run configuration.